# Hysteresis in finite automata

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata

The concept of [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) seems well suited to describe and distinguish finite automata:

> "Hysteresis is the dependence of the state of a system on its history." <sub>(Wikipedia, *Hysteresis*)</sub>
>
> "[The state of a finite state machine] is determined by its history.
>   <sub>(Minsky, *Computation*)</sub>

What I am looking for is a definition of hysteresis *strength* $H$ of finite automata distinguishing finite automata with a stronger dependence on history from those with a weaker one. In the most simple case $H$ would be real-valued with $H=0$ for memory-less automata*. But more complex definitions might be more appropriate, e.g. to distinguish automata that simply store the last input forever and automata that can recognize complex regular expressions.

What seems clear to me is that $H$ must be related to and reflect the complexity of a regular expression describing the automaton (in terms of size, nestedness, etc.)? And it must be related to the complexity of the state diagram (in terms of size, cycles, etc.). But it should not be *identical* with these complexities.

> Is there already such a definition of hysteresis strength for
>   finite automata?

---

*Memory-less automaton:

[image]

Comment: "What I am looking for is a definition of hysteresis strength $H$ of finite automata distinguishing finite automata with a stronger dependence on history from those with a weaker one."  That seems just way too vague.  Maybe if you told us what you really are attempting, then we could help more?

Comment: One thing that always overlooked with this kind of question, hysteresis is not a property of the system itself.  Hysteresis is a property of the description of the system.  You can have the same system represented 2 different ways, one with a dependence on it's entire history and one with no dependence on it's history at all.  And further complications is that state machines depend not on history of states but on history of inputs.   So what you are asking becomes unclear.

Comment: Where do I learn more about "hysteresis as a property of the description of the system"? In which text book, e.g.?

Comment: crossposted on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36992/hysteresis-in-finite-automata